# Asp .net core how to display RTF document file in page view cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Please I need some help.

I want to build an online exam web application, so the question files as .rtf stored in database, then when the exam held, us as participant can see the questions by the button list in page.

How I can show/display any .RTF file document (from my database) to page view (.cshtml) ?

```
public class Exam_Question
        {
            ....
            public byte[] Question_File { get; set; }
        }
```

I have stored the file in database.

Then in controller I call the model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
     var exam_Question = await _context.Question.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
     return View(exam_Question);
}
```

Then in page view I did try this.

```
<iframe src="data:@Model.Question_File; base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Question_File)"></iframe>
```

the result like this image : [IFrame tag with base64 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVIjR.png)

I want to display at least at same bold, size, paragraph, equation, etc format like in Word App.

Answer (score 2):

I think one option will be to convert the RTF into HTML at server side and then rendering.

You could either use a paid library as below

[SautinSoft](http://www.sautinsoft.com/convert-rtf-to-html/rtf-to-html-component-asp.net.php)

Or build your own RTF to HTML converter. Here is a link to CodeProject which provides pretty detailed breakdown

[CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/recipes/rtfconverter.aspx)

Sorry I cant think of a simpler solution at the moment

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I think will be more easy if I store the converted rtf file as html in database, then load it to page view.
btw, this answer is helpful for me, I will try I'm figured it now.

Comment: If all you need is text content, you can get a decent rendering of the content by stripping out certain patterns via Regex

Answer (score 0):

As a variant: Load RTF file and then to open in HTML.

```
        string inpFile = @"..\..\..\..\example.rtf";
        string outfile = Path.GetFullPath("Result.html");
        
        RtfToHtml r = new RtfToHtml();
        r.Convert(inpFile, outfile, new HtmlFixedSaveOptions() {Title = "Show the RTF." });
```